# how to install linux-headers-3.5.0-32-generic

Tags: server, apt, kernel, lts

When i try to install some apps i get a message:

```
linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal : Depend: linux-headers-3.5.0-32-generic but it is not installable
```

uname -a

```
Linux ubuntus 3.5.0-27-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 19:33:56 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

dpkg -l | grep linux-image

```
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic      3.5.0-23.35~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic      3.5.0-27.46~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-28-generic      3.5.0-28.48~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-30-generic      3.5.0-30.51~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-31-generic      3.5.0-31.52~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-3.5.0-32-generic      3.5.0-32.53~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal   3.5.0.32.39                  Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Answer (score 0):

If the following command works, then you should be able to install the package.

> apt-cache search linux-headers-3.5.0.32-generic

*linux-headers-3.5.0.32-generic* package is part of the software sources *quantal-security*, *quantal-updates* and *quantal-proposed*.

Hence one of the above software sources has to be ticked in

> Ubuntu Software Center >> Edit >> Software Sources >>> Updates

Answer (score 0):

install synaptic and find the headers there. It will resolve the dependencies.